# Set operations with networkx

Tags: python, graph, set-operations

I am working with networkx and I need to do set operations. Particularly I want to do an intersection between to set of edges.

The operations I need involve EdgeView type and set type. The problem is that with the set type the couples within it are ordered, but the graph is undirected, there is no order.

How could I solve in a clean and efficient way?

Example of the issue; suppose an undirected graph G with an edge (0,1):

```
print((1,0) in G.edges)
print((1,0) in G.edges & {(0,1)})
```

The code above prints True followed by False. It would be reasonable that set operations keep that consistance - i.e. True twice.

Comment: Can you clarify what you think ``(1,0) in G.edges & {(0,1)}`` does? ``&`` is the *intersection*, so for any set ``s`` ``s & {(0, 1)}`` is ``{(0, 1)}`` or the empty set. There is no point doing that test – what little it depends on ``G.edges`` is not relevant for the outcome.

Comment: I did the edit to clarify the case. The point in that example is to highlight the fact that networkx does support set operations, but the output is not and EdgeView anymore. Hence, after the operation edge (u,v) is different from edge (v,u)

Comment: So you want to convert the result of an EdgeView set-operation back to an EdgeView (or similarly behaving type)?

Comment: It could be a solution, but I can't do allocation of EdgeView. Am I right?